# Function takes 'random' time of execution

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

I have problem with understanding the performance subject.

I have a simple function which takes an array, a return length of the longest raising sequence of numbers. It's working well, but I'd like to test how long it takes depends on the length of the array in the input.

```
 const getMaxSequence = (arr) => {
 const t1 = performance.now();
    if (arr.length === 0) return 0;

    let maxSeries = 1
    let currentMax = 1

    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] > arr[i-1]) {
      currentMax += 1
      maxSeries = Math.max(maxSeries, currentMax)
    } else {
      currentMax = 1
    }
    }
  const t2 = performance.now();
  console.log(`Option ${arr.length}  ${t2-t1}`)
  
   return maxSeries;
} 
}
```

I added a test cases generator to check the time of execution. It creates an array with raising numbers, so the function always goes the same path inside. `options` is an array of cases length, which by `makeArray` func is changing into an array of a given length.

```
const makeArray = (n) => (new Array(n))
.fill(1)
.map((_, i) => i)

const options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map((x) => x*100000)

const randoms = options.map(makeArray )
```

Logic says that in that simple function, the longer array is gives, the more time it takes to calc. But the result of the console.log() inside function gives:

`randoms.forEach(getMaxSeries)`

```
// Console
"Option 100000  3.920000046491623"
"Option 200000  5.200000014156103"
"Option 300000  0.5949999904260039"
"Option 400000  0.8300000336021185"
"Option 500000  1.6549999127164483"
"Option 600000  1.6799999866634607"
"Option 700000  2.35999992582947"
"Option 800000  1.5849999617785215"
"Option 900000  2.265000017359853"
"Option 1000000  1.990000018849969"
```

What can be the reason of that?

Comment: A single test for an array doesn't tell you anything about the "performance". You have to do multiple tests with the same array and get the average to get a rough idea of the actual time it takes. There are just too many sources that can interfere with the execution of your script. Have a look at https://jsperf.com and/or https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com

Comment: Thank for that answer, I tried to do call every case 10 times, but the results was the same as above. But after your answer, I tried 100 times for every case and the average result  are actually better (raising)